# How to set nested (json like) environment variables for crontab

Tags: python, docker, cron, environment-variables

I have environment variables such as

```
VAR1={'key1': 5, 'key2': 8}
```

or `VAR1="{'key1': 5, 'key2': 8}"`

to be used in a script which works as an environment variable. I want to use this inside a .env file to be used with a cron job like so:

```
* * * * * /etc/.env python script.py > src/out.log
```

The script works with the above example of the environment variable. And it also works when I used this inside a docker container and specify the environment variable to the docker.

**However the syntax of the environment variable does not seem to work when using it with cron. why is that?**

why is this syntax correct with normal python script and docker, But not correct with cron?

cron is outputting:

```
.env: 1: 5,} not found
```

Comment: is the environment variable in a .env file or on the os? You could also try `VAR1='{"test1": 1, "test2": 2}'` and then `json.loads(os.getenv('VAR1'))`

Comment: it is inside a .env file. I am loading the variables like so `printenv > /etc/.env`

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to write like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "/etc/.env python script.py > src/out.log"
```

The error message seems to execute `/etc/.env` file.